# Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined in google charts

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

as the title saying im getting this error when trying to get charts inside function in another file like this

functions.php

```
 function get_likes($catid){
     require dirname (__FILE__).'/dbfunction.php';
  ?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/charts_min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/functions.js"></script>
 <?php
 /// myquery here fetching the likes from database
 ?>
  <script>
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  </script>
 <?php
 if ($polls->execute()) {
 while ($row = $polls->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <script>

    a= <?php echo 2; ?> ;
    b= <?php echo 3; ?> ;
    c= <?php echo  5; ?> ;
    i= <?php echo  $row['id']; ?> ; ///// this i is looped to id 31 and 32
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(a,b,c,i)}); ////But this didnt loop and it prints one chart for id 31. Because when i make alert(i) inside drawChart it alerts two times 31 and 31 .
    </script>
    <?php
     echo "<div id="Votes_container"></div>";
   }
}
```

my functions.js

```
   function drawChart(a,b,c,i) {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['do', a],
      ['ri', b],
      ['me', c]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'',
                   'width':500,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('Votes_container'+i));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

my index.php

```
    require 'includes/functions.php';
    $id = 1 ;
   get_likes($catid) ;
```

So when i load index.php i want to get charts which gets data from database and come with get_likes() function , but my try didnt realise and it throws the error in the title . 
where did the mistake located . Please ask me if i forget something before downvoting :) .

thanks for the help .

EDIT: i have edited the id of the divs where it should load the charts but it doesnt work either and same error.

Edited as the comment suggested and it prints the chart but its not looped now throw all ids.

Last Edit : this edit im writing how it worked for me.

I had to declare variables inside the function ,

```
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { 
    a= <?php echo 2; ?> ;
    b= <?php echo 3; ?> ;
    c= <?php echo  5; ?> ;
    i= <?php echo  $row['id']; ?> ;
  drawChart(a,b,c,i)});
```

Comment: The error means google.visualization was not actually defined before you called google.visualization.DataTable.  Your setOnLoadCallback function is actually calling drawChart, not passing the function to be called later.  Wrap it in its own function:  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(a,b,c,i)});  But you will have to do more since the variables, a b c and i won't be what you expect.

Comment: @dlaliberte , you was right :) , im not getting any error now and it displays the chart now , AND exactly as you said i didnt get chart looped inside my while loop to get many charts depends on data gathered from database. is there a clue to that now ? and if you have it please add everything to an answer so i can accept it as helped , i just got chart for the last looped id .

Comment: @dlaliberte Please look to my edit i have commented in two lines to show the problem there inside functions.php

Comment: Your variables are undeclared, so they are globals, so the last change in the last loop will apply to all cases when the drawChart() calls are made.  Using var a, etc, won't help, however, since they will be the same vars in the get_likes function. But declare them with 'let a' etc and it will create new variables for each loop.

Comment: @dlaliberte with let . im getting just chart for id 32. it means the first one looped. the second didnt come,

Comment: Ok i tried something else and it worked :)

Comment: @dlaliberte look my last edit how it worked for me :) , anyway thanks so much its you who solved the error message :)

Comment: I was confused about your while loop, which is actually in php, so your solution of putting the variable declarations inside of the function helps. Still, without 'var' before each variable, those are global variables, but it turns out, each time the function is called, it will set the variables and use them immediately, so you are OK.